# Design pattern for a specific type object creation

Tags: java, c#, .net

Suppose I have a 2 classes: `ValidatorA`, `ValidatorB`, and both have same declaration of `Validate` function: `public void Validate(string input)` (Thus implementing the same interface).

How can I create a single point which will get a **type name**, and send it over to the appropriate `Validate` method it should use ? (In case I do NOT want to use "switch-case"...)

For instance:

Type "Bla" should activate ValidatorA method

Type "Bla2" should activate ValidatorB method

Type "Bla3" should activate ValidatorA method

***P.S***

I thought about using a dictionary in a class, and init it in the constructor like:

```
Dictionary<string,IValidator> dic = new Dictionary<string,IValidator>();
dic["Bla"] = new ValidatorA();
dic["Bla2"] = new ValidatorB();
dic["Bla3"] = new ValidatorA();
```

Then use it:

public void OnePoint(string type,string input)
{
   dic[type].Validate(input);
}

But this way it allows me only a **SINGLE** instance for a type.

Comment: In which language do you want to receive an answer? And at least for java, method names should be using camlCase(), too.

Comment: Why do you think that it allows you only a single instance?

Comment: What 's wrong with what you wrote? Depending on the type, the correct validate method will be triggered (polymorphism)

Comment: May be you'd better use polymorphism for method choosing.

Comment: Yes, all the Validators classes (ValidatorA, ValidatorB..) have a Validate method and according to the type, the correct Validate will be triggered

Comment: @VladimirSerykh single instance because we only create one instance: "new ValidatorA();" is written only once.

Comment: @ohadinho No, it's not. `dic["Bla"] = new ValidatorA();` and `dic["Bla3"] = new ValidatorA();` instantiate two objects of type `ValidatorA`.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh you didn't understand what I mean :). If I get type "Bla"  for instance 4 times in a method, and I'm using it like: dic[type] - I'm getting the same ValidatorA instance, instead of creating an instance to each one of the four times activated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Factory pattern for this. Make a base class for Validator1 and Validator2 class and in that class you can write your validate method. make it virtual one so you can override that method in your separate classes.

```
 public class BaseClass
 {
     public virtual void Validate()
     {
         throw new exception("not implemented");
     }
 }

 public class Validate1 : BaseClass
 {
    public ovrerride void Validate()
    {
        // your validation code
    }
 }

 public class Validate2 : BaseClass
 {
    public ovrerride void Validate()
    {
        // your validation code
    }
 }
```

make another Factory Class to create separate objects.

```
 public static class Factory()
 {
      public static  BaseClass CreateObject()
      {
          // create your validate1 and validate2 objects in here. use if or switch-case according to your requirement.
          return validate1 or validate2
      }
 }
```

you can call to factory class and create Validate1 or Validate2 object as your requirement.

> BaseClass validateObject = FacctoryClass.CreateObject();

and you can call separate validation methods by using this instance.

> ex:  validateObject.Validate();

hope this might be a help for you...

Comment: PS: i'm not a java developer. i'm doing .net

Comment: @ohadinho it's only for creating relevant object. it's not necessary if you can create your class objects separately.